# sqlplus: error while loading shared libraries: libsqlplus.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, oracle, installation, sqlplus, oracleclient

Please suggest a solution for solving this issue?? While giving the command:

```
sqlplus /nolog
```

the error that occurred:

```
 sqlplus: error while loading shared libraries:
 libsqlplus.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: How do you source your environment ? Show us.

Answer (score 36):

The minimum configuration to properly run `sqlplus` from the shell is to set `ORACLE_HOME` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. For ease of use, you might want to set the `PATH` accordingly too.

Assuming you have unzipped the required archives in `/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_1`:

```
$ export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_1
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$ORACLE_HOME"
$ export PATH="$ORACLE_HOME:$PATH"

$ sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 11.1.0.7.0 - Production on Wed Dec 31 14:06:06 2014
...
```

Comment: yes, but only when executables and libraries are all in $ORACLE_HOME/ and not when they are installed in their own dirs like $ORACLE_HOME/bin/ and $ORACLE_HOME/lib/

Comment: @ik_zelf Right. But for some reasons I assumed the OP was using SQL*Plus as provided as part of the [instantclient package](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html). Those are mostly _flat_ archives with all libraries and binaries in the base directory. Of course, if you move the files after having extracted them as explained [here](http://ronr.blogspot.fr/2014/10/how-to-install-oracle-instant-client-on.html) ( ;) ), you have to adjust the various environment variables accordingly.

Comment: With Instant Client you shouldn't set ORACLE_HOME.  The best thing to do is use the most recent version of Instant Client and follow [Oracle installation instructions](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html#ic_x64_inst).

Answer (score 20):

```
sudo sh -c "echo /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf";sudo ldconfig
```

from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Oracle%20Instant%20Client

Comment: Even if you install from a RPM, you still need this little bit of magic sauce that allows sqlplus to work (with corrections to the correct version of the Oracle client, of course).  Setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, as so many other pages suggest, does not work.  It's a shame that it needs to be wired into the system, because it turns it from a "download the client and run it" to "get a syadmin's help to install it".

Comment: Version 18.3 is the current version and this little bit of script will also get around weirdly restrictive sudo permissions:
`echo /usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/lib > /tmp/oracle-instantclient.conf ;
sudo cp /tmp/oracle-instantclient.conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d ;
sudo ldconfig`

Comment: With 19c, the `ldconfig` command is run automatically when the RPMs are installed.

Answer (score 15):

I did solve this error by setting

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$ORACLE_HOME
```

yes, not only $ORACLE_HOME/lib but  $ORACLE_HOME too.

Comment: you should put it on .bash_profile so next time you don't have to enter this command again

Answer (score 9):

You should already have all needed variables in `/etc/profile.d/oracle.sh`. Make sure you source it:

`$ source /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh`

The file's content looks like:

```
ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
export ORACLE_HOME
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH
```

If you don't have it, create it and source it.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's an old thread, but I got into this once again with Oracle 12c and LD_LIBRARY_PATH has been set correctly.
I have used `strace` to see what exactly it was looking for and why it failed:

```
 strace sqlplus /nolog
```

sqlplus tries to load this lib from different dirs, some didn't exist in my install. Then it tried the one I already had on my LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

> open("/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/lib/libsqlplus.so", O_RDONLY) = -1
>   EACCES (Permission denied)

So in my case the lib had 740 permissions, and since my user wasn't an owner or didn't have oracle group assigned I couldn't read it. So simple `chmod +r` helped.

Comment: This helped me to find out the cause. The installer is really awful. I had to reinstall it so the paths are correct.

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu Server 20.04 and using instant client version 19.10.0.0, I used alien to install the rpm package. I got this error when I just used the -i option. However when, I added -c I did not have this issue. from the man page for alien:

> -c, --scripts
> Try to convert the scripts that are meant to be run when the package is installed and removed.  Use this with caution,
> because these scripts might be designed to work on a system unlike
> your own, and could cause problems.  It is recommended that you
> examine the scripts by hand and check to see what they do before using
> this option.

So it seems the correct configuration (in 19c) or the environment variables (in earlier versions) are set in these scripts which are not generated unless you run alien like this. (Thanks @Christopher Jones for correcting me on this)

```
sudo alien -i -c BasicPackage.rpm
sudo alien -i -c SqlPlus.rpm
```

Comment: To be technical, the 19c (and later) RPMs create `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf` and run `ldconfig`.  There is no environment variable

Answer (score 3):

PERMISSIONS:
I want to stress the importance of permissions for "sqlplus".

1. For any "Other" UNIX user other than the Owner/Group to be able to run sqlplus and access an ORACLE database , read/execute permissions are required (rx) for these 4 directories :

   $ORACLE_HOME/bin , $ORACLE_HOME/lib, $ORACLE_HOME/oracore, $ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus
2. Environment. Set those properly:

   A. ORACLE_HOME
        (example: `ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oranpgm/product/12.1.0/PRMNRDEV/`)

   B. LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   (example: `ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oranpgm/product/12.1.0/PRMNRDEV/lib`)

   C. ORACLE_SID

   D. PATH

   ```
    export PATH="$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH"
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can try usage:

```
# echo "/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf
# ldconfig
```

This problem are because oracleinstant client not configure shared library.

Answer (score 2):

On Oracle's own Linux (Version 7.7, `PRETTY_NAME="Oracle Linux Server 7.7"`
 in `/etc/os-release`), if you installed the 18.3 client libraries with

```
sudo yum install oracle-instantclient18.3-basic.x86_64
sudo yum install oracle-instantclient18.3-sqlplus.x86_64
```

then you need to put the following in your `.bash_profile`:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$ORACLE_HOME
```

in order to be able to invoke the SQLPlus client, which, incidentally, is called `sqlplus64` on this platform.

Comment: It's much easier to use the 19c Instant Client RPMs which do the equivalent configuration for you without you needing to set environment variables.  Also, with Instant Client you shouldn't set ORACLE_HOME.  And the general recommendation is to use `ldconfig` instead of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` if possible - check the Instant Client installation instructions.

Comment: @ChristopherJones Thank you for the tip. I installed the 18.3 client because when I ran `yum search instantclient` on the abovementioned system, only that showed up (this is an "Always Free VM" in the Oracle Cloud BTW). I assume the 19c Instant Client RPMs must be downloaded separately or some other repo must be added to `yum` -- I haven't had time to explore that option yet. But I was somewhat surprised to see that so much after-configuration is needed after installing a package...

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me: `sudo dnf install libnsl`

Answer (score 1):

Could you please check if LD_LIBRARY_PATH points to the oracle libs

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget

```
apt-get install libaio1 libaio-dev
```

or

```
yum install libaio
```

Answer (score 0):

It means you didn't set ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID variables. Kindly set proper working $ORACLE_HOME and $ORACLE_SID and after that execute sqlplus /nolog command. It will be working.

Answer (score 0):

@laryx-decidua: I think you are only seeing the 18.x instant client releases that are in the `ol7_oci_included` repo. The 19.x instant client RPMs, at the moment, are only in the `ol7_oracle_instantclient` repo. Easiest way to access that repo is:

`yum install oracle-release-el7`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on Oracle documentation, check the runtime link path
ie. https://www.oracle.com/fr/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html

> If Instant Client is the only Oracle Software installed on this system
> then update the runtime link path, for example:
>
> ```bash
> sudo sh -c "echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_3 > \
>       /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf" 
> sudo ldconfig
> ```

Using docker image nginx:stable

```bash
apt-get update -y
apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get install -y wget
apt-get install -y unzip
apt-get install -y libaio1

mkdir /opt/oracle
cd /opt/oracle

wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/219000/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.9.0.0.0dbru.zip
unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.9.0.0.0dbru.zip

wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/219000/instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-21.9.0.0.0dbru.zip
unzip instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-21.9.0.0.0dbru.zip

wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/219000/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.9.0.0.0dbru.zip
unzip instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.9.0.0.0dbru.zip

sh -c "echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_21_9 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf"
ldconfig

export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_9
export LD_LIBRAY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME

sqlplus
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case /Red Hat) I had to install `libnsl` :

```
yum install libnsl.x86_64
```

With the command "strace sqlplus /nolog" I found:

> openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libnsl.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

And googling I found the solution.