# libsqlplus.so: connot open shared object file : No such file or directory even though PATH contain the path

Tags: oracle11g, client, shared-libraries, ubuntu-12.04

I downloaded Instant Oracle Client Version 11.2.0.4.0(`basic`, `sqlplus`, `devel` .rpm file) by [Oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html) in Ubuntu.
After converting `.rpm` into `.deb` using `alien`, I installed it, `basic` first and `sqlplus` and last `devel`.

And then I tried to run sqlplus.

But It is saying `sqlplus64: error while loading shared libraries: libsqlplus.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Even though my `PATH` contains the `PATH`.

The below shows my `PATH` and the location of `libsqlplus.so`.

```
A@ubuntu:~$ sudo find / -name libsqlplus.so
/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libsqlplus.so

A@ubuntu:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/sangmin/eclipse:/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib:/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Test your Oracle client. User either *sqlplus* either *sqlplus64* depending on your platform. In my case, I used:

```
$ sqlplus64 username/password@//dbhost:1521/SID
```

If you get the next message, then you need to instruct sqlplus to use the proper libray:

> sqlplus64: error while loading shared libraries: libsqlplus.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

To do so, first find the location of Oracle libraries. The path should be something like `/usr/lib/oracle/<version>/client(64)/lib/`. In my case (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, Intel on 64-bit), it was `/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/`.

Now, add this path to the system library list. Create and edit a new file:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf
```

Add inside the path:

```
/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/
```

Run now the dynamic linker run-time bindings utility:

```
$ sudo ldconfig
```

If sqlplus yields of a missing `libaio.so.1` file, run:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libaio1
```

For other errors when trying to run `sqlplus`, please consult the Ubuntu help page.

Comment: Oracle's installation instructions at the base of http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html did not hint of the need to edit the system library list. Thank you for this.

Comment: there is no `oracle.conf` in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`

Answer (score 0):

Might worth checking the permissions issue:
[sqlplus: error while loading shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37468719/4991300)

PERMISSIONS:
I want to stress the importance of permissions for "sqlplus".

1. For any "Other" UNIX user other than the Owner/Group to be able to run sqlplus and access an ORACLE database , read/execute permissions are required (rx) for these 4 directories :

   $ORACLE_HOME/bin , $ORACLE_HOME/lib, $ORACLE_HOME/oracore, $ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus
2. Environment. Set those properly:

   A. ORACLE_HOME
        (example: `ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oranpgm/product/12.1.0/PRMNRDEV/`)

   B. LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   (example: `ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oranpgm/product/12.1.0/PRMNRDEV/lib`)

   C. ORACLE_SID

   D. PATH

   ```
    export PATH="$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH"
   ```

Comment: It's helpful to include an explanation of your advice, rather than just a link.